# How to repeat code; If user inputs no. I want all three loops to repeat, until user inputs Yes

Tags: java, while-loop, repeat

```
// First loop for number of quarters
int quarter;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter number of quarters (1-10): ");
    if (keyboard.hasNextInt() && (quarter = keyboard.nextInt()) >= 1 && quarter <= 10)
        break;

    keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard bad input
    System.out.println("Number of quarters must be between 1 and 10");
}
keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard rest of line
System.out.println("You have " + quarter + " quarters.");
// Second loop for the rate of intrest
double intrestRate;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter interest rate (5%-25%), without percent sign: ");
    if (keyboard.hasNextDouble() && (intrestRate = keyboard.nextDouble())  >= 5 && intrestRate <= 25)
        break;

    keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard bad input
    System.out.println("Interest rate must be between 5% and 25%");
}
keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard rest of line
System.out.println("You have selected a " + intrestRate + "% rate of  interest.");

// Third loop
double balance;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter beginning principal balance, that is greater than zero: $");
    if (keyboard.hasNextDouble() && (balance = keyboard.nextDouble()) > 0);
        break;
}
```

Okay so assume, at this point, there is another branch asking if the *Input above is correct, type Y for yes, or N for No. If they type Y i can easily get the code to break. But, How could I make it to where if the user types in N (IgnoreCase) that the whole branch starts again? So, if the user inputs No. The program will repeat, Loop 1 through Loop 3 until they are satisfied. (Loops displayed in //code.

Comment: thank you, I'm still pretty new to Java @Bob

Comment: Still your question is not formatted well! It's hard to read.

Comment: @S M Al Mamun Is this any better? This is a hard question for me to ask also :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking in terms of your code, but in general, a way to restart a part of your code if the answer is No would be to put that section of code in a while loop.

```
//initialize a String to "No"

while(user input is "No"){
     //your segment of code
System.out.println("Is this correct?");
// take user input by method of your choice. Yes will break out of loop, no will go back to start of while loop
}
```

Comment: So, if you look at my code and i have a string that asks if the input is yes. IF it read out that the user typed No i can use your code and it will restart from Loop 1?

Comment: Do you want to ask this yes or no question before or after your three loops of code?

Comment: AFTER the code. It prompts for their inputs, once it resolves. Then it prompts for a Are these values correct? Yes or No. If Yes, the loop breaks and the program ends "or moves on once i figure out where im going with then. But, if they type No, i want the code to reprompt all the information from the beginning

Comment: What you can do is initialize a String/whatever your input method is to No, put all of the code that you posted in a `while(input is no)` loop, then also in the loop, after your code, ask if the values are correct. If the user inputs yes, it will break out of the code. If the user inputs no, the code will begin from the beginning.

Comment: Hmm, I somewhat understand that. So While (No = false) and it will run through the program, but when the user inputs No, No = true then it repeats ? Hmm, maybe Im not understanding how to do this. Is there any way you could use a small example?